# What is a Basis Swap Curve?

Tags: yield-curve, swaps

I know what a Swap Curve is. But I don't understand what a Basis Swap Curve is and how it is constructed?

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Where did you see this term ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://thinxlabs.com/blog/finance/basis-swap-curves-pricing/) you can find what you need for.

It explains how to build & price a basis swap curve in a step-by-step procedure.

The link leads on the 2nd page to the guide (relative to the question), but, I suggest you to start from the 1st post.

Comment: The link is no longer working